# Tabpage is empty after adding user control to vb.net tabpage

Tags: vb.net, tabs

I am trying to display an usercontrol(**has several panels one on top of the other panel**) on tabpage. I am using below code to achieve this.

```
Dim ctrl As TechniciansControl = New TechniciansControl
TabControl1.TabPages(2).Controls.Add(ctrl)
```

The problem is that the control doesn't show anything. I verified the control is created correctly. The tabpage is empty. **It works for other usercontrol which has only one panel.**

Appreciate any ideas to fix this issue.

Comment: So you want to add a control to the panel control inside the TabPages(2). Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the control is visible and, also, make sure that it's location is within the viewable client area of the tab control.